# Creating Forms with Joins in Symfony 2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, formbuilder

Now I'm trying to create Forms with the Symfony 2 Formbuilder. 
I have a Table "Client" with a join on the Table "Address".

I want a form with the fields of Client and some fields of Address.

All the fields should be Textfields.

Thats what im done so far, but I'm wondering if this is really the best practice or if theres an better way to solve this.

I created for the table address an extra type and added it in the client type.

The Client Type is used for the FormBuilder.

AddressType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('street')
        ->add('company');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Test\UserBundle\Entity\Address',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'Address';
}
```

ClientType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('Address', new AddressType());
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Test\UserBundle\Entity\Client',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'Client';
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the best practice, and we have been doing this as a team. I hope you have mapped ORM relationship with cascade persist, so that address entity saves with a Client relationship when form submits.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like the best practice, which consists in using embedded forms.
You can find more about that here :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms